# Beautifulsoup/Writer returns an empty cell when exported to a CSV

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, csvwriter

I'm scraping a website to get the name, birth + death dates, and the name of the cemetery someone is buried in. For the most part, it is working quite well; however, when I exported the text to a CSV, I noticed that there's a blank cell inserted in the name column after each page. I have a feeling this is probably related to the loop rather than an html tag, but I'm still learning. Any advice is welcome! Thanks everyone

[Here's an example of the problem in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToU0F.jpg)

```
from dataclasses import replace
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv 

api = 'https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/search?'
name = 'firstname=&middlename=&lastname='
years = 'birthyear=&birthyearfilter=&deathyear=&deathyearfilter='
place = 'location=Yulee%2C+Nassau+County%2C+Florida%2C+United+States+of+America&locationId=city_28711'
memorialid = 'memorialid=&mcid='
linkname = 'linkedToName='
daterange = 'datefilter='
plotnum = 'orderby=r&plot='
page = 'page='
url = api + name + "&" + years + "&" + place + "&" + memorialid + "&" + linkname + "&" + daterange + "&" + plotnum + '&' + page
```

```
for page_no in range(1,93): 
   url_final = url + str(page_no)
   page = requests.get(url_final, headers = headers)

   #print(page)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
   graves = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'memorial-item py-1'})
   #print(graves)

   

   #Getting the Names 
   grave_name = soup.find_all('h2', {'class':'name-grave'}) 

   #Dates
   dates = soup.find_all('b', {'class':'birthDeathDates'})

   #Graveyard Name
   grave_yard = soup.find_all('button', {'role': 'link'})
   #print(grave_yard)

   dataset = [(x.text, y.text, z.text) for x,y,z in zip(grave_name, dates, grave_yard)]
   with open('Fernandiabeach3.csv', 'a',) as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(dataset)
```

I've tried to see if there were any similar tags happening at the beginning of each new page, but I couldn't find anything that stood out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change**

```
with open('Fernandiabeach3.csv', 'a',) as csvfile:
```

**to**

```
with open('Fernandiabeach3.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
```

**In simple terms:**

since you haven't defined how the new line should be it was adding rows

**In technical terms:**

The csv.writer module directly controls line endings and writes \r\n into the file directly. In Python 3 the file must be opened in untranslated text mode with the parameters 'w', newline='' (empty string) or it will write \r\r\n on Windows, where the default text mode will translate each \n into \r\n.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi louis joseph, thank you so much for this! This definitely saves me a step with cleaning the CSV (I was pulling it into Stata and deleting every odd row). 

There's still this one problem with the CSV - it still includes a blank in the name field right before a new record on the next page. I'm adding a screenshot to the post now!


PS: I've definitely been enjoying learning python through this project - it's definitely very different than Stata programming - my bread and butter program.

Comment: your code is not scrapping any data so the field is being returned as blank

Comment: while looking around the site for how the data is received in the site I found that it has an API URL that returns a JSON format output which you can change to CSV.

Comment: https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/search?ajax=true&skip=40&limit=20&firstname=&middlename=&lastname=&birthyear=&birthyearfilter=&deathyear=&deathyearfilter=&locationId=city_28711&location=Yulee%2C%20Nassau%20County%2C%20Florida%2C%20United%20States%20of%20America&memorialid=&datefilter=&orderby=r&photofilter=&gpsfilter=&famous=&cenotaph=&flowers=&sponsored=&noCemetery=&includeNickName=&includeMaidenName=&includeTitles=&hasPlot=&plot=&partialLastName=&exactName=&linkedToName=&fuzzyNames=&mcid=

Comment: Thank you louis! I'm embarassed I didn't know this API existed. You have saved me so much time and helped me with writer syntax. I really appreciate it!

Comment: happy to help. I just found out the API provides 100 sub-data at a time max. Hope this helps. Happy coding :)